# How to see the MDB deployed in Jboss 7 EAP

Tags: ms-access, jboss7.x

I am newbie in Jboss. I have deployed some big war which has lot of MDBs in Jboss 7 EAP. How can I see them from the admin console?

Answer (score 1):

In Wildfly 10 (which I think is used in JBOSS 7 EAP) web console you can access MDBs in the deployment tab.

Open your big war by clicking the "view" button) then go to subsystem > ejb3 > message-driven-bean.

Finally you get a list of all deployed MDBs and their properties. (Delivery active true/false, etc...)